# Join on Single record from left table Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:

left table

```
DATE       |ID  |Cust_id    |TYPE
2018/08/15 |1   |   25      |LN    
2018/08/15 |1   |   81      |LN
```

Right table

```
DATE       |Cust_id |TYPE   |status
2018/08/15 | 86     |LN     |T
```

I want to keep all records from left table and only bring in the `status` field from the right table:

Desired results are the following:

```
DATE       |ID  |Cust_id    |TYPE   |Status
2018/08/15 |1   |25         |LN     |1
2018/08/15 |1   |81         |LN     |null
```

The issue is that the `Cust_id` becomes different on the right table making the join difficult to join on the correct record from the left join.

Comment: "the Cust_id becomes different on the right table", please explain in more detail how these tables are connected.

Comment: Then what is the logic to join your 2 tables?

Comment: Also, where does `Status = 1` come from?

Comment: Your posted data contains no fields that can be joined uniquely. What logic would join _Cust_id_ 25 with the record containing _Cust_id_ 86?

Comment: @tinyiko . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  It is quite unclear what you are trying to do.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question, which would include a clear explanation of what you are trying to do (in particular, what matching logic do you want to use).

Comment: @ HoneyBadger my mistake status should be T. There are no keys to connect both tables. i tried to use different fields to create a unique join but i need to keep all records from the left table and only one of the  record should have the status as T. @Mackan Our DB became messed up, so now i cannot join using cust_id column to join to status column to get the correct record. if at least i  could join  status to one of the record in the left table that would be helpful otherwise if they both have status T it would be seen as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select left.*,right.status from left_table left
left join right_table right
on r.cust_id = left.cust_id
```

The above is to join the two tables on the basis of the cust_id and the status will always be null if you dont have matching ones .

in your case its not possible to get the status because it does not have any relation .. Besides to view without relation you can join both tables e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM left_table
UNION
SELECT status FROM right_table
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select l.*,r.status from left_table l
left join right table r
on r.cust_id = l.cust_id
```

if your cust_id's do not represent the same info on different tables there is no way you can join the 2 tables

Comment: Thanks for the feedback i thought there could be a work around for this.

Comment: you are welcome, please mark my reply as an answer if it covered you